# import views vs from . import views

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-3.10

I am new to Python and Django, I have an app directory called *`calc`* and inside it there are two files:

1. `views.py`
2. `urls.py`

In `urls.py`, if I type in `import views` the server generates an error, however if I type `from . import views` everything works fine. Could someone explain why? I thought since the two py files are in the same directly, the import statement should match the views.py

Comment: the `.` is your immediate direcory. if your are in urls.py it shares same directory with views.py so basically you are saying from my current directory import the file views.py

Comment: Thanks @Martins but isn't import views the same?

Comment: it's not the same, hence the error.

Comment: this is only for Django? I created a temp folder with two py files:

1. temp1.py
2. temp2.py

in temp1.py I wrote a simple function called func1 which will print hello world.

in temp2.py I typed in the following:

import temp1
temp1.func1()

and it worked

Comment: @Martins, for import views I thought Python will search a list of directories and one of them is the immediate directory of the script, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple. By default if you `import everything`, you are importing it from standard pythonish library. If you expand it to `from everything.something import anything` it checks the path starting with app `everything` modules. If not successful, it also tries to look for global.

In your case it looks inside same folder (starting `.`) for module `views` which isn't global package, so it cannot be achieved by simple `import views`.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing though, I thought the "standard pythonish library" already includes the directory from where the python script is running, no?

Comment: No, with "standard pythonish library" I mean modules that are built-in the Python, like `time`, `requests` and such. Directories are inside project, not Python itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are in your `calc` module, you have to use `import calc.views`, not `import views`.

You can then refer to some `view` function `some_func` as `calc.views.some_func`.

Or you could do `import calc.views as views`, and then you can refer to the function as `views.some_func`, the same as when you use `from . import views`.

The reason you have to include the `calc` prefix with `import calc.views` is because that is considered an "*absolute import*", and `calc` itself is not in your `$PYTHONPATH` -- its parent directory is.

In any case, you are probably better off sticking with `from . import views` (which is referred to as a "*relative import*").

Answer (score 0):

Python looks up models from location specified by sys.path

1. `project\tempFolder` (where both temp1.py and temp2.py reside)

Add in print(sys.path) to temp2.py. It will show both `project\` and `project\tempFolder` (together with some other folders)

> I created a temp folder with two py files: 1. temp1.py 2. temp2.py in
> temp1.py I wrote a simple function called func1 which will print hello
> world. in temp2.py I typed in the following: import temp1
> temp1.func1() and it worked

2. `MyDjangoProject\calc` (where both views.py and urls.py reside)

Add in print(sys.path) to urls.py. It will only show `MyDjangoProject\`(together with some other folders)

So in order to reach views.py from urls.py, you will can use relative path, or absolute path from root package. Both work!

```
from calc import views

from . import views
```